# configure apache such that any domain pointing to ip address to redirect to a folder

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm newbie to apache config.

Is it possible to configure apache dynamically such that any domain pointing to IP address using A Records to redirect to  a folder in my server?

Please assist me how this can be done or check to do this task.